# First N values of a function with two inputs

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinations

I have a function with two integer inputs like this:

```
function f = func(n, m)
    a = 2;
    b = 1;
    f = sqrt((n/a)^2 + (m/b)^2);
end
```

m and n are integers and greater than or equal to zero. The first couple of values of f and the inputs they occure in are like below:

n ----- m ----- f

0 ----- 0 ----- 0

1 ----- 0 ----- 0.5

2 ----- 0 ----- 1

0 ----- 1 ----- 1

1 ----- 1 ----- 1.118

and so on. I want to get the first N values of f and their respective n and m. Is there an easy way to do that in matlab?

Comment: With `0, 1 and 2` you would get upto `9` values in `f` it seems, so what if your `N` is larger than `9`? Or do you mean something like `0, 1, 2, 3 and so on till N`?

Comment: In this example N is five so I get the first 5 values of f. As you can see after (2,0) inputs are (0,1) to get the closest value of f to the previous one. So they don't have any general order. I need to find the correct order of n's and m's to calculate f's in rising order.

Comment: You can use any of the answers, then sort the result wrt value `f` and take the first N elements. The non-obvious point is the size of the grid n*m to compute for not missing any value, as it strongly depends on the function `func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Parameters
N = 5
a = 2;
b = 1;

%// Extents of n and m would be from 0 to N-1 to account for all possible
%// minimum values of f results resulting from their use 
len1 = N-1

%// Create n and m for maximum possible combinations scenario, but save
%// them as n1 and m1 for now, as the final ones would be chopped versions
%// of them.
[n1,m1] = ndgrid(0:len1,0:len1)

%// Get corresponding f values, but store as f1, for the same chopping reason
f1 = sqrt((n1(:)./a).^2 + (m1(:)./b).^2);

%// Sort f1 so that the smallest N values from it could be choosen and also
%// get the selected row indices based on the sorting as row1
[f1,row1] = sort(f1)

%// Choose n and m based on the sorted indices and also chop off at N.
%// Use these n and m values to finally get f
n = n1(row1(1:N))
m = m1(row1(1:N))
f = f1(1:N)
```

**Output**

With N = 5, you would get -

```
n =
     0
     1
     2
     0
     1

m =
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1

f =
         0
    0.5000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.1180
```

With N = 9, you would get -

```
n =
     0
     1
     2
     0
     1
     2
     3
     3
     4
m =
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     0
     1
     0
f =
         0
    0.5000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.1180
    1.4142
    1.5000
    1.8028
    2.0000
```

Comment: +1 Pretty much exactly how I would have done it. Perhaps explaining a little more would make it even better.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks buddy! And sure that's coming up!

Comment: Thanks That does it really good. I, too, will really appreciate a little explaining.

Comment: @soroosh.strife Edited with some comments. Check those out if they make sense!

Comment: I think you should omit sqrt from len1. Some valid results are lost this way.

Comment: @soroosh.strife On second thought and after doing some experiments on larger numbers, you seem to be right. Edited accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

[`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) can be used to generate an array of outputs for ranges of inputs as such

### Code

```
nValues = 0:2 
mValues = 0:3

[ii,jj] = meshgrid(mValues,nValues)
output = arrayfun(@func,ii,jj)
```

The two value vectors can be modified to take the range(s) of values required

### Output

```
output =

         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000
    1.0000    1.1180    1.4142    1.8028
    2.0000    2.0616    2.2361    2.5000
```

---

To give a result like the matrix in the question the following can be used (thanks @Divakar)

```
[jj(:),ii(:),arrayfun(@func,jj(:),ii(:))]

ans =

         0         0         0
    1.0000         0    0.5000
    2.0000         0    1.0000
         0    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.1180
    2.0000    1.0000    1.4142
         0    2.0000    2.0000
    1.0000    2.0000    2.0616
    2.0000    2.0000    2.2361
         0    3.0000    3.0000
    1.0000    3.0000    3.0414
    2.0000    3.0000    3.1623
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ii(:)` and `jj(:)` with `arrayfun`? Good idea with `meshgrid` btw! +1

Comment: good idea, i'm going to add to set it to match the format given using ii(:) & jj(:)

Comment: It's actually close to what I'm looking for. I should sort these results and pick the first N of them. Isn't there a way that doesn't need calculating extra results?

Comment: For the function given its probably possible by working out relationships between m & n values which will give the same results (eg [2x,0] & [0,x]), although assuming this is just an example function. I can't imagine it being more efficient than brute force when considering using it for many different funcitons

Answer (score 1):

Something (probably rather inefficient) like this?

```
N = 100 % stop 
i = 0
n = 0
m = 0
nout = [n]
mout = [m]
fout = [f(n,m)]
while i ~= N
    a = f(n+1,m)
    b = f(n,m+1)
    if (a > b)
        m = m + 1
        nout = [nout n]
        mout = [mout m]
        fout = [fout b]
    else 
        n = n + 1
        nout = [nout n]
        mout = [mout m]
        fout = [fout a]
    end if
    i = i + 1
end while
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is calculating the correct input values of the function in order not to miss anything in between and have consecutive outputs. And I can't do that with hand since N can be somewhat large.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question. You want to calculate f for all PAIRS of values from [0..N] is that right?

Comment: No. in the example I've given above I have calculated the first 5 values of f. But in order to do so I tried different combinations of values for m and n to make sure these f's can not have any other values in the range 0 to 1.118. The problem is instead of 5 I need for example the first 100 values of f and I don't know what combinations of inputs to use.

Comment: I see now. You're really sorting numbers on a paraboloid: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2F2%29^2+%2B+y^2

Not exactly efficient, but you could simply step through values of n and m, increasing by 1 on one number, calculate the value of func for that particular (n,m) pair, and grow vectors on the smaller value of f. I'll edit my post

Comment: Actually sometimes when I increase one input by one if I decrease the other one I get a closer value of f to the previous one. As is the case with (2,0) and (0,1) in my example.

Comment: foiled again. Can you tell us how large N is? If it's small enough can you do with generating extra unneeded values?

Comment: if you check the first five outputs of this code you get [0 0.5000 1.0000 1.4142 1.8028 2.2361]. This is because you should not aways increase m an n.

Comment: N is around 100 so in this example if I want the first 100 values for f I need to calculate 10000 f's ( I think)

Comment: @soroosh.strife Actually calculating 10000 values of f is not a lot. It will probably take a fraction of a second. Improving on the algorithm is nice, but in fact you may be over-optimizing.